# regex pattern for matching dd mm only

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I am looking for a data pattern for matching date 1 to 31, and the month January to December, right now I am using this pattern `([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]).[a-zA-Z]` but it is not working well, please tell me what is wrong with this pattern.

the output should be like this -

01 Jan - 31 Jan,

1 Jan - 31 Jan,

1 January - 31 January,

[image]

Comment: with this pattern, the date is taking more than 2 digits

Comment: Missing `+` in the end? What is not working well?

Comment: please check I have attached an image, the issue is that it working fine 1 to 31 digits but is also working with greater than 31, which I don't want

Comment: If my answer did not solve your issue please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with below regex:

```
\d{1,2}.[a-zA-Z]{3,8}
```

[image]

Comment: it should not work with greater than 31 also

Answer (score 0):

Note I included only months starting with capital letters:

```
reg = "\b( -?\d{1,2} [JFMAMSOND][a-z]{2,8}) \b"
```

This will get the first part, for example 01 Jan, to get the whole sentence ( 01 Jan - 31 Jan, ):

```
reg = "( -?\d{1,2}[ ]?[JFMASOND][a-z]{2,7})[ ]?-[ ]?\d{1,2}[ ]?[JFMASOND][a-z]{2,7},$"
```

The [ ]? is optional for spaces, remove ? if you sure you need spaces. The same thing applies for last comma, remove it if you don't need to look for a comma at the end.

Comment: The question has tag js, so you won't need to mention python

Answer (score 0):

With regex you can't directly recognize a number range like 1-31, but you can combine a few ORed patterns:

```
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('1 Jan')
true
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('01 Jan')
true
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('10 Jan')
true
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('25 Jan')
true
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('30 Jan')
true
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('31 Jan')
true
/^(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) +[JFMASOND][a-z]+$/.test('32 Jan')
false
```

Explanation:

- `(?:` ... `)` - non-capturing group, used to OR patterns
- `0?[1-9]` - numbers 1-9, with optional zero padding
- `|` - OR
- `[12][0-9]` - numbers 10-29
- `|` - OR
- `3[01]` - numbers 30-31
- `+` - 1+ spaces
- `[JFMASOND][a-z]+` - initial caps letter from Jan-Dec, followed by 1+ lowercase letters
- if you want to be more strict with the month you could explicitly state all months with abbreviation, such as `(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|` ... `)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s*(?:Jan(?:\.|(?:uary)?\b)|Feb(?:\.|(?:ruary)?\b)|Mar(?:\.|(?:ch)?\b)|Apr(?:\.|(?:il)?\b)|May\b\.?|Jun(?:e?\b|\.)|Jul(?:y?\b|\.)|Aug(?:\.|(?:ust)?\b)|Sep(?:\.|(?:tember)?\b)|Oct(?:\.|(?:ober)?\b)|Nov(?:\.|(?:ember)?\b)|Dec(?:\.|(?:ember)?\b))/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUoTgp/2/). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` - a number from `1` to `31` with an optional leading `0` for numbers from `1` to `9`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:Jan(?:\.|(?:uary)?\b)|Feb(?:\.|(?:ruary)?\b)|Mar(?:\.|(?:ch)?\b)|Apr(?:\.|(?:il)?\b)|May\b\.?|Jun(?:e?\b|\.)|Jul(?:y?\b|\.)|Aug(?:\.|(?:ust)?\b)|Sep(?:\.|(?:tember)?\b)|Oct(?:\.|(?:ober)?\b)|Nov(?:\.|(?:ember)?\b)|Dec(?:\.|(?:ember)?\b))` - each month name, either abbreviated with an optional dot after the month name or a full month name, but each should be a whole word (no matching in `31 Maydays`).

**However**, this is not checking date validity. To do that, use a post-processing step in JavaScript after you get your matches.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = `01 Jan - 31 Jan,
1 Jan - 31 Jan,
1 January - 31 January,
998 December and ! - 31 February`;
let matches = text.match(/\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s*(?:Jan(?:\.|(?:uary)?\b)|Feb(?:\.|(?:ruary)?\b)|Mar(?:\.|(?:ch)?\b)|Apr(?:\.|(?:il)?\b)|May\b\.?|Jun(?:e?\b|\.)|Jul(?:y?\b|\.)|Aug(?:\.|(?:ust)?\b)|Sep(?:\.|(?:tember)?\b)|Oct(?:\.|(?:ober)?\b)|Nov(?:\.|(?:ember)?\b)|Dec(?:\.|(?:ember)?\b))/gi);
console.log(matches);
// Now, show only valid dates:
const months = {jan:"01",feb:"02",mar:"03",apr:"04",may:"05",jun:"06",jul:"07",aug:"08",sep:"09",oct:"10",nov:"11",dec:"12"};
const parseDate = function(s){
  var [_,d,m] = s.match(/^(\d+)\s*(\w+)/);
  return `${new Date(Date.now()).getFullYear()}-${months[m.substring(0,3).toLowerCase()]}-${d}`;
}
matches = matches.filter(x => moment(parseDate(x), 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid());
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you friends for your response, but I fixed it by my self using this pattern and it is working perfectly fine

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[123][0-1]|.[a-zA-Z])\b
```

Comment: This is wrong since [it will also match junk](https://regex101.com/r/mY646q/1).

Comment: Please don't mark me negative, It doesn't matter if it doesn't match the text, my goal was to match the number only, for me it works, I think you didn't understand what was the question, user can type any kind of text, like (Dec, dec, DeC, December, Dcmbr), I need to match the only number, in my case, it is working well

Comment: No, you explicitly mention in the question that you need to extract the month name.

Comment: that month name was the only example, that month would be Jan, Feb, march, etc...

Comment: So please don't mark me negative, brother

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|[123][0-1]|.[a-zA-Z])\b
```